# Bootstrap 3.3.6 positions elements badly wrong

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I was trying to use [this example](h /snippets/featured/thumbnail-with-caption-amp-buttons) from official bootstrap site, but... it seems to fail totally when some of elements is different height...

[image]

Was trying different configurations of styles, but I didn't manage to fix that... could somebody help? Second line may be a bit more to the bottom, but so it would always be 6 elements per row!

Putting everything in different row (every 6) doesn't change situation at all.

Comment: It's the height of your images. Make sure they're all the same size.

Comment: they are, but description is not! the only reason I used bootstrap was because i thought it will fix the problem with different heights... but I guess it doesn't...

Comment: What does your code look like where you're going through your list of products?

Comment: List of products with names that can vary from 10 to 255 characters.

Comment: is it? I don't think so, as when I change box size to bigger (the first one) in the answer of that question, it still acts the same as in my case.